# Save profile bug or update?

Tags: bug, profile-page

I recently went to edit my profile and saw this:

[image]

This seems quite different. After clicking "customize your profile just on this community" I see this:

[image]

Also the two buttons need to be rearranged to not be so close to each other.

I entered the page by pressing settings, edit profile in the navigation bar. I am on Chrome (version 103.0.5060.71) for Android, resolution 2220×1080 on mobile.

Comment: TL;DR: neither bug, nor update. Old time behavior, not commonly known.